# Magento Reindex Issue on Product Attributes

Tags: product, database, catalog, reindex

I have started a reindex and it was taking too long so I closed the process and restarted mysql.
Now , when I'm tring to run from command line

```
php indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_attribute
```

I'm getting this error

```
Product Attributes index process unknown error:
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction' in /var/html/www/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
0 /var/html/www/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
1 /var/html/www/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
2 /var/html/www/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
3 /var/html/www/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
4 /var/html/www/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('DELETE FROM `ca...', Array)
5 /var/html/www/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('DELETE FROM `ca...', Array)
6 /var/html/www/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(664): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('DELETE FROM `ca...')
7 /var/html/www/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(235): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->delete('catalog_product...')
8 /var/html/www/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Eav/Abstract.php(49): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Abstract->clearTemporaryIndexTable()
9 /var/html/www/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Eav.php(185): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Eav_Abstract->reindexAll()
10 /var/html/www/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(143): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Eav->reindexAll()
11 /var/html/www/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(212): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
12 /var/html/www/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(260): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
13 /var/html/www/shell/indexer.php(168): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
14 /var/html/www/shell/indexer.php(217): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
15 {main}

Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction, query was: DELETE FROM `catalog_product_index_eav_idx`' in /var/html/www/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235
Stack trace:
0 /var/html/www/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
1 /var/html/www/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
2 /var/html/www/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
3 /var/html/www/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('DELETE FROM `ca...', Array)
4 /var/html/www/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('DELETE FROM `ca...', Array)
5 /var/html/www/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(664): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('DELETE FROM `ca...')
6 /var/html/www/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(235): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->delete('catalog_product...')
7 /var/html/www/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Eav/Abstract.php(49): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Abstract->clearTemporaryIndexTable()
8 /var/html/www/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Eav.php(185): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Eav_Abstract->reindexAll()
9 /var/html/www/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(143): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Eav->reindexAll()
10 /var/html/www/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(212): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
11 /var/html/www/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(260): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
12 /var/html/www/shell/indexer.php(168): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
13 /var/html/www/shell/indexer.php(217): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
14 {main}
```

When doing this a few times  I logged in to mysql and ran a

> show processlist;
>   I tried to increase the lock wait timeout to 1000 even and it still blocked.

The table has 9 million+ rows - maybe that is a factor of why it's taking so long ?
What to do please ?

Comment: I'm running Magento 1.9 on 12 cores with 32 GB of RAM - SamuraiJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can first check other posts, for solving lock wait timeout.
e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836623/getting-lock-wait-timeout-exceeded-try-restarting-transaction-even-though-im

Running a Full Magento Index, is consuming a lot of power.

Have you tried to run the full reindex at a time, your shop has less visits?

On our Magento Shop system, when doing full reindex, we're truncating (not deleting ) the magento index table. For catalog attributes you can truncate these

TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_eav`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_eav_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock_status`;

But use at your own risk. Then start the indexer.

We're also working with master/slave setup, that all reading-queries are fired on our slave. So starting index processes is no problem

Comment: I have used this on my dev site and it worked , would you be so kind to give me the tables that need truncating for the prices index? Cheers..

Comment: yes.TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock_status`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_final_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price`;

Answer (score 0):

check the mysql process list  by :-

> SHOW PROCESSLIST;

then  kill the sleep process first

> kill $Id (of th processes)

then run the reindex command

> php bin/magento index:reindex